# Как отключить обертку в Spring для Lazy

Tags: java, spring, swing

Есть класс PanelLogo, который расширяет **JPanel** (Swing класс). Над классом PanelLogo ставлю аннотацию `@Component`.
Есть класс Basic одно из полей которого  `@Autowired private PanelLogo panelLogo;` И вот когда в методе `init` с аннотацией  `@PostConstruct` я обращаюсь к panelLogo, вижу, что это уже не PanelLogo, а `PanelLogo$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$261ab916`, и Spring в лог выводит:

```
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:39 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
    INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@735b478: startup date [Wed Apr 19 16:01:39 MSK 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:39 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
    INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [basic-context.xml]
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:42 PM org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy doValidateClass
    INFO: Unable to proxy method [final java.awt.Container java.awt.Window.getContainer()] because it is final: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:42 PM org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy doValidateClass
    INFO: Unable to proxy method [void java.awt.Window.connectOwnedWindow(java.awt.Window)] because it is package-visible across different ClassLoaders: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:42 PM org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy doValidateClass
    INFO: Unable to proxy method [java.lang.String java.awt.Window.constructComponentName()] because it is package-visible across different ClassLoaders: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:42 PM org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy doValidateClass
    INFO: Unable to proxy method [void java.awt.Window.postProcessKeyEvent(java.awt.event.KeyEvent)] because it is package-visible across different ClassLoaders: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
    апр 19, 2017 4:01:42 PM org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy doValidateClass
    INFO: Unable to proxy method [void java.awt.Window.addOwnedWindow(java.lang.ref.WeakReference)] because it is package-visible across different ClassLoaders: All calls to this method via a proxy will NOT be routed to the target instance.
```

после чего падает исключение:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.awt.Container.checkGD(Container.java:1168)
    at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Container.java:1091)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:1003)
    at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(JFrame.java:564)
    at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:971)
    at ru.ezhov.schedulerproductiontasks.components.authorization.AuthorizationForm.addPanelToFrame(AuthorizationForm.java:94)
    at ru.ezhov.schedulerproductiontasks.components.authorization.AuthorizationForm.init(AuthorizationForm.java:64)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:134)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1138)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver$1.getTarget(ContextAnnotationAutowireCandidateResolver.java:83)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:192)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.setVisible(Unknown Source)
    at ru.ezhov.schedulerproductiontasks.components.basicframe.startApp.RunnableAuth.lambda$run$0(RunnableAuth.java:44)
    at ru.ezhov.schedulerproductiontasks.components.basicframe.startApp.RunnableAuth$$Lambda$7/99494787.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:744)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:714)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Думаю, что Spring оборачивает класс в обертку, но как ему сказать, чтоб он просто инстанцировал класс без обертки?

UPD: причина такой работы в аннотации @Lazy как над компонентом PanelLogo, так и над полем PanelLogo.

В доке к `@Lazy` прямо написано про прокси для поля с `@Autowired`:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Lazy.html

Есть ли возможность это обойти?

Comment: ленивый бин обязателен?

Comment: вы опять пытаетесь использовать Spring там где не нужно его использовать.

Comment: так и решил проблему убрал все @Lazy, спасибо.

Comment: @Mikhail Vaysman, я в Spring только начинаю разбираться, изучаю по Spring in Action, и прочитал довольно занятную фразу, которая говорит о том, что Spring можно применять в любом проекте от Desktop до BigData, но одно из основных направление, конечно WEB, так как на данный момент основной проект это проект на Swing, параллельно изучаю и пробую применить в разных моментах.